# Почему присвоенная функция к onclick сразу вызывается?

Tags: javascript, dom

Я не могу понять почему присвоенная функция сразу вызывается. Как сделать подобный метод?

```js
  button.onclick = function() {
    alert('Clicked');
  };
```

Comment: что значит "сразу вызывается"?

Comment: Ну я так понял, что onclick это метод. И в моем понимании этот код должен выглядеть так: button.onclick(function).
Но тут мы, вроде бы, переопределяем метод onclick и присваиваем ему функцию, которая сработает при нажатии на кнопку.

Comment: ну так она и срабатывает при нажатии - что не так?

Answer (score 2):

Ничего сразу не запускается, пока не нажмете

```js
button.onclick = function() {
    alert('Clicked');
  };
```

```html
<button id="button">Жмем!</button>
```

Comment: Так я понимаю, что функция срабатывает при нажатии на кнопку. Я не понимаю почему она вообще срабатывает, мы же переопределили метод onclick присвоив ему эту функцию. 
P.S. метод onclick приведен в качестве примера. У таких методов под капотом могут быть и другие условия выполнения функций.

Comment: мы переопределили обработчик для этого события. Когда оно происходит, вызывается наша функция

Comment: Alex, const button = document.querySelector('button');
console.log(button.onclick);
button.onclick = function() {
 alert('hello');
}
console.log(button.onclick); вставьте этот код в какой-нибудь песочнице, откройте консоль и поймете что происходит